# What has happened to this question?

Tags: support, profile-page, title, mathjax

***Note***: I thought this may be an issue network-wide (at least, where Tex coding and MathJax are embedded) and it could be a bug, so I posted it here. If it helps, I'm using a win8 OS and a Google Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.118 m)

---

[This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29002/how-can-i-balance-this-equation-atomically-and-electrically-cec2o42-mno) in Chemistry.SE has a chemical equation in the title, while there's no such thing in the question's title in the question page. The URL for the question has a `-cec2o42-mno`, which is part of the question's body. Have fun taking a look at some screenshots, and yes, there is so much "freehand" (MS Paint style) that would satisfy you, I hope: (*Oh, and oh my god, I used arrows!*)

[image]

And a screenshot from the question page shows no such equation in the title:

[image]

So,

- I thought URL slugs created the URL from the question title. Why is there some of the question body in the URL?
- What has really happened to this question? Why can I see something in the "newest questions" tab while the *real* question title doesn't contain those chars?

Comment: The original title did have MathJax -- http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/29002/1. My bet would be caching... http://shouldiblamecaching.com. ;)

Comment: Lies, those circles/ellipses are not freehand.

Comment: @pizza This world is deceiving. BTW, I did say "MS Paint style". :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As hichris123 said: caching happened. The first revision of the question had an equation in the title. It was edited out. The question lists and the slug in the URL did not update instantly. But they are up to date now.

Comment: +1 Hmm, well, that didn't happen *instantly*, so I doubted it. Clear now. Thanks.